# adding color to the checkbox on the third click

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

- In angular 2 I am trying to change the checkbox for third click
- so after the tick mark for the third click it should the small box as red color.
- can you tell me how to achieve it.
- providing my code below.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3s6hsh?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

```or-tag-here
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  //var count = 0;

  // public items: Array<string>;
  public count = 0;

  constructor() {
    // this.items = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
  }

  getStyle(event) {

    // var target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;
    // console.log("target--->" , target);
    // var idAttr = target.attributes.id;
    // console.log("idAttr--->" , idAttr);

    // var value = idAttr.nodeValue;
    // console.log("#"+value);


    const style = `color: red`;
    console.log("style--->" + style);

    return style;

  }

  public open(event) {

    let count = 0;
    let countIncreased = count + 1;

    if (count % 3 == 0) {
      console.log("getStyle started--->");

      var target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;
      console.log("target--->", target);
      var idAttr = target.attributes.id;
      console.log("idAttr--->", idAttr);

      var value = idAttr.nodeValue;
      console.log("#" + value);

      value.css(`color: red`);
      //value.addCs

      this.getStyle(event);
      console.log("getStyle ended--->");

    }

    alert('Open--->' + countIncreased);
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this (it uses jQuery):

```
// declare var to count clicks
var counter = 0;

// attach event to button
$('#buttonId').on('click', function () {
    counter = counter + 1;
    if (counter > 2) {
        // apply new style
        $('#buttonId').css('background-color', 'red');
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply...can you tell me how to achieve in angular 2

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the variable `rememberCount: number;` within your component and bind it with the checkbox:

```
export class AppComponent {
  rememberCount: number;

  constructor() {
    this.rememberCount = 0;
  }

  public open(event) {    
    this.rememberCount++;

    if (this.rememberCount % 3 == 0) {
      .
      .
      .
      .
    }    
  }
}
```

In the component's template (HTML) bind the model `rememberCount` and pass the js event object `$event`.

```
<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]='rememberCount' name="rememberLogin" id="test"  (click)="open($event)">
                                  ^                                                            ^
```

Comment: hey updated the code but still its not working,,can you help me https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-edjr68?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: You're trying to call `value.css()` over a string variable